# Как интегрировать GitHub в Atom?

Tags: git, github, atom, интеграция

Установил Atom, не могу найти где настройки интеграции с GitHub-аккаунтом. Перерыл поисковик, ответа не нашел.

Comment: Может быть [это](http://blog.atom.io/2014/03/13/git-integration.html) Вам поможет? Есть ещё [**Atom+**](https://atom.io/packages/git-plus)

Comment: @EgorTrutnev к сожалению, там нет информации об интеграции самого аккаунта. В настройках атома тоже всё перерыл.

Comment: А [это](https://github.atom.io)?

Comment: @EgorTrutnev тоже смотрел, но вся проблема в, что и там нет.

Comment: А что вы хотите делать на гитхабе из Атома?

Comment: @D-side Push, PR и прочее.

Comment: Не нужно интегрировать атом с гитхабом. Вы же программист — откройте консоль и работайте через нее, она простая и надёжная.

Comment: Множество инструментов программиста – консольные приложения: git, make (и прочие автоматизаторы задач: rake, grunt, maven...), diff, grep, sed, curl. Научитесь с ними работать, это плюс и к вашим способностям и в резюме.